# I am transit in Doha to Mumbai. May I have several bibles in my check-in bags?

Tags: transit, gcc

I will travel to Mumbai in few days.  My flight will trasit in Doha to the final destination.  What I have concerned about is traveling with my bibles.

I know that Gulf Cooperation Council (GCC) countries only allow a personal use bible for their visitors. Well I have seven of them for this trip. I am going to pack them in my check-in bags.

I assume it will be ok since I am visiting, just transiting.

Any thought?

Comment: Bibles are freely available in India. I'm curious as to why you need to carry several with you?

Comment: Bibles are freely available in Qatar, too. I've never heard of any import restriction on them.